# Django URL error using parameters

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm new to Django so I expect a fare amount of confusion, however I thought this one is interesting so I am puzzled by the following, I have link A and link B (both doing the same thing)...

urls.py

```
url(r'^testing/([\w\s-].+)/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', 'testapp.views.test_view', name='test'),
```

template page

```
<a href="{% url 'test' i.name i.id %}">{{i.name}}</a>
<a href="{% url 'test' i.name i.id %}">{{i.name}}</a>
```

Link A gets through while Link B produces the error below:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch

Reverse for 'test' with arguments '('8', '109404')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['test/([\\w\\s-].+)/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
```

I've tried encapsulating the parameters, double checking the data being passed, I even tried passing the same data through link A and then B.

Anyone having the same issue? what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your first capturing group:

```
r'([\w\s-].+)'
```

Here you first have a character set with no quantifier: `[\w\s-]`. This matches a single character. Then you have a dot (any character) with the `+` quantifier, i.e. one or more. This means you need at least two character: One matching `[\w\s-]`, and one or more matching `.+`.

You probably mean to capture the first character set one or more times, i.e.:

```
r'([\w\s-]+)'
```

Comment: @Jason Define "didn't work". Do you have a traceback?

Comment: Because your arguments sometimes don't match your url pattern.

Comment: not true, for example: I pass /somename/01 and it works sometime and sometimes it doesnt. Also if I change the dynamic URL on the template to static it works everytime

Comment: Also if I change the dynamic URL on the template to static (<a href="test/{{i.name}}/{{i.id }}">{{i.name}}</a> it works everytime

Comment: Alright, show the traceback, the view, anything that might help us help you.